# plugin defaults are not overridden in jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have the following code:

```
$.fn.newActivity = function(ops) {
    var defaults = {
        name: "activityNew",
        actionBar: "true"
    };
    var ops = $.extend( {}, defaults, ops);
    var newElem= $("<div>");
            newElem.addClass(defaults.name);
    return this.append(newElem);
};
```

Now when I call the plugin like this:

```
$("body").newActivity({
    name: "menu",
    actionBar: "false"
});
```

The new options I set when calling the plugin does not override the default options. What do I have wrong in my code please. I have searched Google and still can't find the mistake in my code.

More Information
When I run the code, I expect the `div` element to be appended to body and have a class of `menu`.

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/4XKSt/ . Can you expand the issue you are facing?

Comment: Its properly working,on above fiddle ,whats the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using the `default` object var not the `ops`, try using ops instead.

`ops` will contain the passed options extended with the default provided inside the plugin code.

Code:

```
$.fn.newActivity = function(ops) {
    var defaults = {
        name: "activityNew",
        actionBar: "true"
    };
    var ops = $.extend( {}, defaults, ops);
    var newElem= $("<div>");
            newElem.addClass(ops.name);
    return this.append(newElem);
};

$("body").newActivity({
    name: "menu",
    actionBar: "false"
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hn3Q/